# Ruby rails - RoutingError for Assets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My development rails env can't read image files. I added `config.serve_static_assets = false` in `development.rb`. But that didn't resolve. What else I need to change here?

```
Started GET "/assets/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png" for 10.10.10.10 at 2012-05-12 22:02:32 -0400
Served asset /images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png - 404 Not Found (45ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png"):
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your `config/application.rb` is configured to use the asset pipeline.

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Also, make sure your file is in the right place

```
/app/assets/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
```

And now that you mention that you're using jQuery UI, you need to make sure that the asset can be found. Typically, you'd want them to be found at:

```
/vendor/assets/images/*
```

How you make that happen is up to you. You could copy all the images from wherever they are in the jQuery UI download to that directory.

Comment: And config.assets.debug = true  ?

Comment: I am using jQuery UI. The image file names always changing. don't know how does jQuery track its assets.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this revelation.

Comment: Mark Paine you are truly my hero. Converted from Rails 4.0 to Rails 3.2 and my assets where not found, why? because the line you mentioned first was simply not there. Thanks for your answer